# C++ Altering the borders of an external application window

Tags: c++, c, cmd, window

I want to make a custom border or simply remove the border for another window (another application). However the way I've done it currently (with GetWindowLong, SetWindowLong & SetWindowPos functions) removing the border causes graphical issues for one program (cmd.exe) and does nothing at all for another (heroes of might and magic II).

I'm not very familiar with C++ yet and don't know how to go about doing this. I want simple and clean-cut borders so I for example could place a cmd.exe on the taskbar or play HoMM2 in borderless full screen.

Anyone knows how this can be achieved?

Here's my current function:

```
void noBorder(HWND win)
{
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(win, GWL_STYLE);  
    style &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME |
WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_BORDER);  
    SetWindowLong(win, GWL_STYLE, style);  
    style = GetWindowLong(win, GWL_EXSTYLE);  
    SetWindowLong(win, GWL_EXSTYLE, style | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);  
    SetWindowPos(win, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE |
 SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
}
```

Comment: cmd.exe does not have a window in newer Windows versions. Try altering conhost.exe  (which displays GUI for cmd.exe) or pick an easier target for a start. For example - notepad.exe

Comment: You mean I should try to embed conhost.exe? What my current program does is to grab the open window passed as an argument to the program's main and then remove the borders of that window.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, by altering I meant not embedding. I meant find the associated window and alter its styles.